# JAI I/O Tools missing when launched with java whereas present when run with Maven

Tags: java, maven

My java program involves PDFs. Some of them have JPEG2000 images embedded. So I added the following lines to my pom.xml :

```xml
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.26</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>1.26</version>         
</dependency>

<!--Please note the absence of jai imageio core 
to make the program work. It will be provided by tika parser -->        
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>  
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>

...

<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
         <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>0.0.8</version>
         <configuration>
            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>enforce-maven</id>
               <goals>
                  <goal>enforce</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                  <rules>
                     <requireMavenVersion>
                        <version>3.3.9</version>
                     </requireMavenVersion>
                  </rules>
               </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.3.0</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                  <archive>
                     <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                     </manifest>
                  </archive>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                     <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
               </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
         <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
         <configuration>
            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.10.0</version>
         <configuration>
            <release>11</release>
            <source>${javaVersion}</source>
            <target>${javaVersion}</target>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Now if I run the program (from the project directory) with Maven : `/pathTo/netbeans/java/maven/bin/mvn "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath" -DOMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1 -DskipTests=true exec:java` the JPEG2000 dependency is loaded and the program works as expected.

However if I run the program (from the project directory) with Java : `java -Dprism.order=sw --module-path /home/user/pathTo/lib/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib  --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH -verbose:class -jar target/myBig-jar-with-dependencies.jar` I get "org.apache.pdfbox.filter.MissingImageReaderException: Cannot read JPEG2000 image: Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) Image I/O Tools are not installed" although JAI and JPEG2000 do appear in loaded classes (see `-verbose:class`) :

> [7,434s][info][class,load] com.github.jaiimageio.jpeg2000.impl.J2KImageReader source: file://path/to/project/target/myJar_with_dependencies.jar [7,434s][info][class,load] javax.imageio.ImageReadParam source: jrt:/java.desktop [7,435s][info][class,load] com.github.jaiimageio.jpeg2000.J2KImageReadParam source: file://path/to/project/target/myJar_with_dependencies.jar [7,435s][info][class,load] com.github.jaiimageio.jpeg2000.impl.J2KImageReadParamJava source: file://path/to/project/target/myJar_with_dependencies.jar [7,435s][info][class,load] com.github.jaiimageio.jpeg2000.impl.J2KMetadata source: file://path/to/project/target/myJar_with_dependencies.jar

To make the program work as expected with `java` I have to put the JPEG2000 jar in the lib path provided to the `--module-path` argument. But I'd rather only have clear dependencies in pom.xml to ease maintain the code in the future, instead of having also dependencies in the JavaFX lib folder in user directory.

So my question is what is the equivalent java command to the maven command shown above ?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this could help since it sounds more like wizardry! I updated to Tika 2.3 (moved *tika-parser* dependency to *tika-parsers-standard-package*) and as I got "package org.apache.tika.config does not exist" (although it does), **I finally restarted Netbeans**, built the jar, launched it via `java`command and it is now working as expected.